# How to select multiple variables on variables filter of Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux, grafana-variable

I've configured a variable called "product" which contains the following values:

```
prod1,prod2,prod3,prod4
```

I've already selected the multi-value option as the image below:

[image: Multi-value select variable]

The measurement in influxdb is something like that:

```
col1    col2    col3
A       prod1   10
B       prod2   20
C       prod3   30
D       prod1   40
E       prod4   50
```

So I don't have a row with the col2 set as `prod1+prod2`. When I try selecting `prod1` and `prod2` on my dashboard variable, I get `No Data`

Is there a different way to configure the variables for my dashboard so I can select multi-values correctly? Or do I have to create the rows `prod1+prod2`, `prod2+prod3` on my Influxdb measurement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to use [Advanced variable format options](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/), the "Regex" option should resolve your problem.

See more info about formatting multi-value variables [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/formatting-multi-value-variables/) too.